# Creating div function in Haskell from scratch

Tags: haskell, math

My Prof asked us to write our own `div` and `mult` function in Haskell with just `+` `-`.
So I wrote the `mult` function like this

```
mult1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
mult1 x 1 = x
mult1 x y = x + mult1 x (y-1)
```

And it worked. Then I tried to code the div like this:

```
div1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
div1 0 y = y
div1 x y = if x < y then x else 
div1 x y = 1 + div1 x (x - y)
```

Can someone explain to me how to fix this problem?

---

**Solution for div**

```
div1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer  
div1 0 _ = 0
div1 x y = if x == y then 1 
  else if x >= 2*y then 1 + div1 (x-y) y 
  else if x > y && not(x >= 2*y) then 1 
  else 0
```

Comment: How would you do that in another language?

Comment: Forget language. How would you do that on a piece of paper?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would do it with a while loop..

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  That's what I did the last hour but I have absolutely no clue how..

Comment: @leftaroundabout yea I know. And so I did try it for a whole day now but I can't figure out the Solution..

Comment: You're still changing the _denominator_ in every recursive call. Does that make sense?

Comment: `mult`  will never terminate if `y` is non-positive.

Comment: Do you really think `div 3 4` should equal 3?

Comment: And should `div 7 2` equal `1 + div 7 5`? You should really try to trace out each step of your algorithm with concrete numbers to see the pattern.

Comment: Yea @chepner  like I said.. I have no clue how to solve this :/

Comment: You can't think of *anything* else in your definition to change? Consider this: what should `div 0 3`, `div 3 3`, and `div 6 3` equal, and how could you define `div 3 3` in terms of `div 0 3`?

Comment: oh thank u so much @chepner . With this "guideline" I solved the problem in 3 minutes. It was way easier as I thought

Answer (score 0):

The base case

> ```
> div1 0 y = y
> ```

is wrong, it should be

```
div1 0 _ = 0
```

Actually you should first check it's not 0/0, but this is a detail. *Actually*, you don't need this clause at all, because it's subsumed by `x<y`.

> ```
> div1 x y = if x < y then x else
> ```

This is incomplete syntax. After the `else` statement there needs to come another expression. In your case, you could just omit the second clause matching `x` and `y`

```
div1 x y = if x < y
   then x
   else 1 + div1 x (x - y)
```

or you could use guards instead of `if`, which is considered somewhat nicer style but really the same thing under the hood:

```
div1 x y
 | x<y        = x
 | otherwise  = 1 + div1 x (x - y)
```

This is still not quite right: think what should really be done in the recursion step. Do you want to trim down the denominator, or the numerator? Can you ever reach `x<y` if you keep `x` the same in the recursive call and reduce `y`?

Comment: You point out that the recursive step isn't right yet; also, the base case isn't right yet.